# PyQt5 QThread freze after termiante

Tags: python, pyqt5

I do have a problem with my application in python with qt5 (I do not have any experience with it). I try to give the user a feedback in form of a textbox, which tells him which data is currently in download. In the first place I tried it with python threads, but I found it works only if I do not access any gui element. So in my research I found about the QThreads to do this. I rewrote my code and it worked fine, till the thread terminates and my gui will freze... If I do not call the `stop` function, it prints enldess and I don't know why ether.

This is my code:

```
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFileDialog, QLabel, QPushButton, QComboBox, QTextBrowser, QProgressBar
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from share.Constants import TERRITORIES_SUBFOLDER_NAME
from share.ExcelOperations import ExcelOperations
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal


class Dataset:

    def __init__(self, excel_ref_number: int, kg_nr: str, grst_nr: str,
                 downloaded: bool) -> None:
        self._excel_ref_number = excel_ref_number
        self._kg_nr = kg_nr
        self._grst_nr = grst_nr
        self._downloaded = downloaded

    @property
    def excel_ref_number(self) -> int:
        return self._excel_ref_number

    @property
    def kg_nr(self) -> str:
        return self._kg_nr

    @property
    def grst_nr(self) -> str:
        return self._grst_nr

    @property
    def downloaded(self) -> bool:
        return self._downloaded

    @downloaded.setter
    def downloaded(self, condition: bool) -> None:
        self._downloaded = condition

    @property
    def header(self) -> str:
        return self._header


class FindDatasets():

    def __init__(self, file_name) -> None:
        self._name = file_name

    def run(self, selected_sheet):
        return [Dataset(1, '2', '3', False), Dataset(2, '3', '4', False)]

    @property # Just to simulate the sheet name extraction of an excel file.
    def names(self):
        return ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2']


class ThreadClass(QThread):
    mySignal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, output_pte, parent=None, find_datasets: FindDatasets = None, sheet_name: str = None):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.is_running = True
        self._selected_sheet_name = sheet_name
        self.find_datasets = find_datasets
        self.output_pte = output_pte

    def run(self):
        print('Starting thread...')
        self._beginDownload()

    def _beginDownload(self):
        ret = self.find_datasets.run(self._selected_sheet_name)

        for element in ret:
            is_alive = self.is_running

            if not is_alive:
                break

            for element in ret:
                status = 'Pending'
                insert_row = f'Downloading:  Nr: {element.excel_ref_number:<10} KG Nr.: {element.kg_nr:<10} Grst. Nr.: {element.grst_nr:<20} Status: {status:<5}\n'
                self.mySignal.emit(insert_row)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        QThread.__init__(self)
        gui_file_path = os.path.join('gui', 'gui.ui')
        loadUi(gui_file_path, self)

        self.find_datasets = None

        self.excel_file_open_btn.clicked.connect(self.open)
        self.begin_download_btn.clicked.connect(self.run)

        self._selected_sheet_name = None

    def open(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file')
        file_name = fname[0].split('/')[-1]
        self.selected_excel_file_lbl.setText(file_name)
        self.selected_excel_file_lbl.adjustSize()
        self.find_datasets = FindDatasets(file_name)

        sheet_names = self.find_datasets.names

        self.drop_down_sheet_names.addItems(sheet_names)

    # TODO Error handling
    def run(self):
        self._selected_sheet_name = self.drop_down_sheet_names.currentText()
        t_begin = ThreadClass(self.output_pte, self,
                              self.find_datasets, self._selected_sheet_name)
        t_begin.mySignal.connect(self.output_pte.insertPlainText)
        t_begin.start()
```

And this is my gui.ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Downloader</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="Downloader">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>648</width>
    <height>407</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QComboBox" name="drop_down_sheet_names">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>280</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>161</width>
      <height>22</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="sheet_names_lbl">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>210</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>71</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Seiten Namen:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="excel_file_open_btn">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Excel-Datei öffen</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QProgressBar" name="progressBar">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>340</y>
      <width>621</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="value">
     <number>24</number>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="begin_download_btn">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>90</y>
      <width>151</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Beginne den Download</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="excel_filename_lbl">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>91</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Excel Dateiname:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="selected_excel_file_lbl">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>107</x>
      <y>42</y>
      <width>121</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Keine Datai ausgewählt</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QTextBrowser" name="output_pte">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>130</y>
      <width>581</width>
      <height>201</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>648</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuDownloader">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Downloader</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuDownloader"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: You've switched to QThread, but you're still trying to access GUI elements. The point doesn't change: you can ***not*** directly access UI elements from an external thread, you ***must*** use signals. Add `mySignal = pyqtSignal(str)` just after `class ThreadClass(QThread):`, use `self.mySignal.emit(insert_row)` instead of `self._writeToOutPut(insert_row)`, then in `run` add `t_begin.mySignal.connect(self.output_pte.insertPlainText)`.

Comment: Note that there's no need for `findChild`, `loadUi` already creates all attribute names based on the object names: use `self.excel_file_open_btn` instead of `self.browse_btn`, `self.selected_excel_file_lbl` instead of `self.name_lbl`, etc.

Comment: Thx for the tipp with the `findChild`  :D. I rewrote the code just as you said, but I'm still stuck after colling terminate. Also it prints my table multiple times, like there are multiple threads started... How is this even possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't provide a [mre], so we don't know what FindDatasets, Dataset, Downloader and FolderCreater are or what they do. Also, you should not call `terminate()` (the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#terminate) also clearly says that it shouldn't be used). You should probably add a check in both those `for` cycles and check for `is_running`, and eventually break the cycles.

Comment: Oh sorry for that. I edit my post to provide the example.